# Retrieve data from one form and use it in another form

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, forms

Alrighty. Here is my problem. I have just about everything done. I just need to take input from the form, and then use it in an algorithm in the second form. I have everything else written up, I just need to know how to connect the 2 so I can write up the last of the code. I've done some research, but none of it seems to go with what I'm trying to do.

Here is the main form.

```
namespace Airplanes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Arrival_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrivalForm newForm;
            newForm = new ArrivalForm();
            newForm.ShowDialog();

        }

        private void Fuel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Fuelform newForm2;
            newForm2 = new Fuelform();
            newForm2.ShowDialog();

        }

        private void Status_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void Items_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void NameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void FuelBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GateBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Singlebutton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PrivateButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CommercialButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

And here is the form I'm trying to connect to the main form.

```
namespace Airplanes
{
    public partial class Fuelform : Form
    {
        public Fuelform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Fuelform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways...the easiest would probably be to pass the data in through the constructor of your new form.

```
FuelForm newForm2 = new FuelForm(myData);
```

And then change the constructor for your FuelForm:

```
public FuelForm(int myData)  // or whatever data type you need
{
    // Deal with myData
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Source form

```
 destinationForm df = new destinationForm ();
            df .myValue= "My Value";
            df .ShowDialog();
```

in Destination Form

```
  private string destVariable;

     public string myValue
            {
                get { return destVariable; }
                set { destVariable= value; }
            }
```

then you can use destVariable everywhere in destination form